# Test if sqlalchemy exception id raised due to wrong password

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, sqlalchemy, pytest

I try to write a test case for a sqlalchemy (mssql+pyodbc engine) connection i have the following function

```
def test_wrong_password(self):
    self.config["DB_Connection"]["password"] = "sdkfajsdklj" #set wrong password
    db = db_interaction(self.config["DB_Connection"])
    with pytest.raises(sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError):
        db.getusername("max.mustermann@example.com")
```

The config for the Database connection is stored in the config dictionary. In the first statement i change the password to some random string. In the second statement i initialize the instance of the the `db_interaction` with  a wrong password.

If i would run the program with the wrong password for user `xxx` i would get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (Error) ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xxx'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)") None None
```

I now want to test, if the connection is refused due to the wrong password and not due to any other Exception.
How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to examine exception with this kind of code:

```
with pytest.raises(DBAPIError) as excinfo:
    # code that raises the exception
    # code withing 'with' block will fail the test if exception didn't happen at all

# code below will additionally check whether exception was really due to failed login
# please note that it's outside of 'with' block

assert 'Login failed' in excinfo.value
```

Have a look into:

- [DBAPIError documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError)
- [Assertions about expected exceptions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions)

Comment: Yes I also thought of comparing the exception message. In the Documentation it says: "The wrapped exception object is available in the orig attribute. Its type and properties are DB-API implementation specific." However when i try this I get the following exception: ´{AttributeError}'ExceptionInfo' object has no attribute 'orig'´

Comment: Could you make a breakpoint there and analyze excinfo in debugger or add writing of dir(excinfo) ?. This should print you attributes that this exception really has.

Comment: Yes that's what I did. It says: "Unable to get repr for <class '_pytest._code.code.ExceptionInfo'>"

Comment: Could you pass exact code you use?

from sqlalchemy.exc import DBAPIError
dir(DBAPIError) gives
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__getslice__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setstate__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__unicode__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_code_str',
 '_message',
 'add_detail',
 'args',
 'code',
 'instance',
 'message',
 'orig',
 'params',
 'statement']

Comment: I think I've got it.... The check should be outside of 'with' block as additional assert. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes this worked. For some strange reason the class does not have an attribute orig but an attribute value, which works accordingly. I'll update your answer and accept. Thanks